# Multiple asynchronous HttpRequests in C#

Tags: c#, httprequest

I have to send two HTTP requests: The second one should be sent while I'm waiting for response from the first one. The responses should be received independently, so it can happen that either response can arrive first. How do I do this in C#? Should I use 2 HttpClients or not and how?

Comment: is this web forms or MVC a console application or something else?

Comment: This is an console application that is loading Web.Api

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes I have resolved it. I'm making 2 HttpRequestMessage, then twice httpClient.SendAsync(request)
so it is

var a=httpClient.SendAsync(request1);

var b=httpClient.SendAsync(request2);

and then I'm getting both responses like

a.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

b.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: Here you are in fact going to wait for the first request to complete regardless of the state of the other, this seems to be contrary to what you asked for.

Comment: no after testing it sometimes the first one arrives first, and sometimes the second one

Comment: Yes, but you're always waiting for nr. 1 first, `a` in this example.

Comment: the fact is that i need both responses in any order. Sometimes I'm receiving the first first and sometimes the second first